# How can I put my Java program in the system tray?

Tags: java, swing, icons

How can I have a system tray icon for my program in Java? I've tried searching all over the web ,but I cant find anything.

Comment: What type of icon do you mean? A Picture in your Swing component? A tray icon? A shortcut icon? Does this tutorial help? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: Then i got a second tutorial, 3 seconds on google later: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

[image: like this?]

See the Java tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

Comment: never thought it was this simple :-)

Comment: :)  Yeap, happens some times.