# Simple way to add window to system tray

Tags: java, swing, jframe, system-tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put my Java program in the system tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264981/how-can-i-put-my-java-program-in-the-system-tray)

I am making a notification system in java, I want the program to show up in the system tray, instead of on the task bar, I have tried:

```
notification.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
```

Not only does this not work, but it lags the heck otta my computer
Current Code:

```
public static void notify(String line1, String line2, String imagepath, int style){
        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int swidth = width - 320;

        JFrame notification = new JFrame();
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        main.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2 , 1 ) );



        JLabel notifyline1 = new JLabel();
        notifyline1.setText(line1);
        notifyline1.setFont(new Font("Minecraft",1 , 16));
        notifyline1.setForeground(new Color(242, 238, 17));
        main.add(notifyline1);

        JLabel notifyline2 = new JLabel();
        notifyline2.setText(line2);
        notifyline1.setFont(new Font("Minecraft",1 , 12));
        notifyline1.setForeground(Color.black);
        main.add(notifyline1);

        notification.add(main);
        notification.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
        notification.setSize(new Dimension(320,64));
        notification.setLocation(swidth, 0);
        notification.setUndecorated(true);
        notification.setVisible(true);
    }
```

ALSO, to kill 2 birds with one stone
is there a way to color a jlabel, tried

```
label1.setForegroundColor(new Color(100, 100, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has `TrayIcon` class which can be used to minimize application to `SystemTray`.You can see the working example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html).